# What is a multivariate $L_p^k$ space?

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The definition I have is:

Define $$\mathbb{R}^k = \{\vec{X} \ |\  X_i \in \mathbb{R}, i = 1,...,k\}$$

then

$$L_p^k = \{\vec{X} \in \mathbb{R}^k \ | \ E|\vec{X}|^p < \infty\}$$

I am trying to understand what the $|\ .\ |$ does. Is it a regular 2-norm exponentiated by $p$:

$$|\vec{X}|^p = \big(\sum_{i=1}^{k}X_i^2\big)^{p/2}$$

or is it a $p$-norm:

$$|\vec{X}|^p = \big(\sum_{i=1}^{k}|X_i|^p\big)^{1/p}$$

The problem I am trying to solve is to show that $$L_p^k < L_q^k, \ \ 0 < q < p$$

The hint is that for any $s \ge 0$,

$$s^q < s^p + 1$$

so put in $|\vec{X}|$ for $s$, take expectations and QED. I think this only works if the norm is the same for both $L^k_p$ and $L_q^k$ though, but then why wouldn't you define the $L^k_p$ space in terms of the $L_p$ norm?